# How to replace JSON using JSON.parse reviver when condition met

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to find a way to completely replace the JSON body when a particular condition is met, using the reviver function in Nodejs:

```
output = JSON.parse(d, reviver);
function reviver(key,value){
        if (condition){
            var mynewjson={'thisis':'whatidlike'};
            return mynewjson;    
        }
    }
console.log(output);
```

But I'm getting undefined as output of the last command.
I've checked the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
and tried couple of things but didn't find the proper way to achieve that.

Comment: What is `d`? What is `condition`? What output do you expect? Provide a real [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You should return value when the condition is not met

```
output = JSON.parse(d, reviver);

function reviver(key, value) {
  if (condition) {
    var mynewjson = {
      'thisis': 'whatidlike'
    };
    return mynewjson;
  }
  return value;
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: hi @Serge thanks for your answer but that's not what I'm looking for..by doing that I will only replace the value where the condition is met..while my goal is to return a completely new json ( {'thisis':'whatidlike'} ) instead of replacing only the current value of the json where the condition is met. Hope this makes sense to you. thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Please give me a little working example showing what you expect if the condition is met and if the condition is not met